# Is it safe to checkout a different Git branch and work during a `cap deploy`?

Tags: git, capistrano

Just like the title says, I'm wondering if it's safe to continue working, changing, switching branches during a `cap deploy`. Is it?

Comment: I've never worked with Capistrano, but changing git branches changes the files on the filesystem, so it's most likely not safe to do that until Capistrano is done reading the filesystem.

Comment: I've never used Captisrano, but I suspect not. Switching branches updates files in your repository; if the `cap deploy` depends on those files, changing them is likely to mess things up. If `cap deploy` instead creates its own clone of your repo from a specified tag or branch, it's probably ok.

Comment: all depends on where you git repo is located, and where you are deploying from.  if you repo is hosted  on a server you can cap deploy in one 1 terminal and do whatever you want on the other.  But if you are deploying from the repo you are currently in (meaning server is connecting back to you, or server is on same box), then you might have issues.

Comment: @Doon Good point. In this case it's precompiling assets locally but deploying from a remote repo. Since the precompiled assets aren't being tracked, I'd guess that means it is safe. Maybe I just won't risk it though.

Answer (score 0):

**capistrano (3.1.0), rails 4.0.2, ruby 2.0**

You can set Capistrano to ask you what branch exactly you want to deploy. For example I run:

```
cap production deploy
```

that means code from production branch will be deployed, once the process started it will deploy the code from github repo/production (my case) to server, meanwhile in another terminal you can checkout different branch and if you have your changes at least committed you can't brake or loose anything.

This line in deploy.rb makes capistrano to ask you before starting the deploy what branch you want to use:

```
ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }
```

Having `master` and `production` branches for example, you'll run `cap production deploy` that will deploy your production code to server even if you are now on master and keep working on your new tasks. After I finish my changes in master, I merge it to production and push it t github, run deploy command and capistrano does the rest while I am on master and working on next features.

So I would deploy while working in another branch but if you are not sure about it, avoid it ;)

Comment: Yes, but the question comes down to whether capistrano uses a working copy on the deployers machine that will be affected if they start working on it, or whether it uses a temp directory or a directory on remote for its work.